# Will aggregation pipeline use index for derived field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In aggregation pipeline I have this:-

```
  {
    "$project" => {
      account_name_i: { "$toLower" => "$account_name" },
    }
  }

  {
    "$sort" => {
      account_name_i: 1
    }
  }
```

and I have index `{ account_name: 1 }`

My Question is will $sort use index on account_name? If no, there is any other way we can achieve this in aggregation pipeline?

Comment: No, it will not, how can it if you have changed the value? To answer the latter: no as well and I know nof no way around this. You are wanting: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Comment: Since, the changed value is function of original value and the output will always be time-invariant (unchanged with time). So, I just thought if it is possible in Mongo

Comment: No, it does not matter. An index can only be used on exact matcing of previous value. Once you change the value to even a different case which changes the unicode values then the index is useless

Answer (score 0):

No. The aggregation pipeline can only use a standard index on a `$match` or `$sort` phase that's at the beginning of a pipeline. The rules for using indexes with aggregation pipelines are described in detail [in the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

You aim to sort on the lower-case version of `account_name_i`, most likely to function as a case-insensitive sort. To achieve this with an index, store a lower-case-normalized version of `account_name_i` in each document

```
{ "account_name_i" : "TruMAn's HABerdaShEry", "account_name_i_lc" : "truman's haberdashery" }
```

and index the normalized field (`{ "account_name_i_lc" : 1 }`).

Comment: This is currently the only method though I say that with huge regret that case insensitive indexes still have not been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Aggregation Pipeline Stages like $group or $match on a collection then it will
produce a new set of documents from that collection.

as it is new set of documents which means no index is defined for it and hence we cant use the index in Aggregation Pipeline

Note: although if you use $sort as first stage of Aggregation Pipeline then it will utilize the index of
the collection as input for this stage is collection itself.

Comment: Since he wishes to sort case insensitive this is not possible since indexes in MongoDB are not case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, though only with preprocessing. You can do an output after your project stage and query the output collection for sorting:

```javascript
db.yourSource.aggregate([
  {
    "$project" => {
      account_name_i: { "$toLower" => "$account_name" },
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "intermediate"
  }
])

db.intermediate.ensureIndex({account_name_i:1})

db.intermediate.find({}).sort({account_name_i:1})
```